# Migrating a NAS while keeping the files and their rights intact?

Tags: migration, network-attached-storage, directory, permissions, shares

Right, what we wish (or need) to do is to migrate a NAS from a old machine to a new one.

problem is, we wish to keep the folder hierarchie intact, and all the settings and shares.

Now I vaguely recall microsoft used to have a tool to do exactly this.

It would copy the folders exactly, with the rights intact, and then remove the shares on the old machine and reactivate them on the new machine.

Now is there anyone who could help me find it again, or perhaps find a better solution for it ?

Much appreciated guys

Comment: Are you going to let us know what products you're talking about?

Comment: its "just" a Microsoft 2003 server right now, running a load of shares (fileserver basicalle) that we need to upgrade to a new box, along with upgrading it to win. 2008 R2 while we are at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using RichCopy. Microsoft tool, works great, decent UI.

Yes I could've used robocopy / FSMT but this works too.

Cheers for any help anyways

Comment: Youve beat me to this one :)...

OP, use richcopy, enable advanced functions and go through the settings after that for full customization. Only there can You set owner+rioghts+acl preservation. Also think about using the log feature. You have to set a new file loaction and name as with some systems logfile wasnt written with defauilt location. I copy and verify a second time with another tool just to make sure. You might want to have the original still at hand before You checked rights preservation

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of the Microsoft File Server Migration Kit (FSMT). Here's a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d00e3eae-930a-42b0-b595-66f462f5d87b&displaylang=en) to the download from their site. FSMT has some pretty stringent OS requirements and is designed to move Windows file servers. Depending on the specifics of your NAS, this may or may not be the tool for you. Maintaining the permissions should be straightforward as long as you don't have local trustees contained in the permissions on the source NAS. If you do have local trustees, you'll need to decide whether to create corresponding local trustees on the destination NAS and repermission the data on the destination. The alternative would be to set up domain trustees and repermission using them. Tools like SecureCopy can help with these types of group manipulations as well as moving the data.